# customize marker layout in wikitude sdk in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, augmented-reality

I am working on augmented view in android using wikitude-sdk.

I am showing marker on screen. Now I want customize marker view using

```
    AR.HtmlDrawable
```

method provided by wikitude-sdk.

can any one have idea about this.

Comment: Open up your Java Script that you use to initialize AR. There you will find some image file names which are stored in your projects assets folder. This links up the marker image from your Assets to AR.

Comment: Thanks friend, but i already done that. This only allow me to change image but not to put my custom html there. Do you know how can i achieve that?

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: Yes, I want to add logo and some extra info for each marker and want to pass click event for each logo and link in extra info. So i want to add my custom html layout for each marker dynamically.

Comment: To customize your markers, you need modifications to your Java Script. You can make changes to the marker only from there. About Click Event, this is also defined in the script itself. However you can override this function from your Activity's code. You need to pass the ID of the Marker from the Java Script, read that ID in your Activity's Code and respond as needed.

Comment: can we place description in 2 lines on marker as currently we are able to place it in singe line provided in example.

Answer (score 1):

I got success in adding extra info by

```
this.descriptionLabel = new AR.Label("IT Company, IT Company, IT Company IT Company, IT Company, IT Company", 0.4, {
    zOrder: 1,
    offsetX: 2.55,
    offsetY: 1.22,
    style: {
        textColor: '#FFFFFF',
        fontStyle: AR.CONST.FONT_STYLE.NORMAL
    }
});
```

adding this code in marker.js

and passing this.descriptionLabel in marker object's cam array to get visible on screen.